# How to create a relevant analysis of a data set of search queries in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, analysis

I've recorded all searches on my website over the past 2 years, but never analysed the data set. I now have around 120k entries with a lot of relevant data it seems.

I hope you guys can help me with how to query this data in a efficient way from the mySQL database, and present the findings in an efficient manner with php.

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id         | SearchQuery |     Timeofsearch      |      User_IP    |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| 201201     |  Football   |  2014-12-28 10:04:06  | 66.249.67.57    |
| 201202     |  Ball       |  2014-12-28 09:36:57  | 68.180.228.101  |
| 201203     |  Handball   |  2014-12-28 09:36:57  | 46.161.41.31    |
| 201204     |  Goal       |  2014-12-28 08:02:18  | 66.249.67.41    |
| 201205     |  Glow       |  2014-12-28 07:24:43  | 207.46.13.30    |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

Some issues:

A lot of the search queries are similar either in topic or how they
   are written.

- Football and Fotball and Footbal should be regarded similar
  (just spelling mistakes)
- Some search queries are similar in topic eg. Nike football, Adidas football, Large football, Small football - they all contain football -> unsure how this should be treated, so open for suggestions.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is difficult to answer, because it is too broad. For example, your mention just _"Some issues"_, which indicates that you are not aware of your requirements. But we can't specify the requirements for you. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27675181/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it just depends on how you want to display the info? You can get some fancy html5 graphs nowadays.

Because you want really need to left join onto other tables you shouldn't take a hit performance-wise.

I'd start just by running something simple like.

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE SearchQuery LIKE '%football%' AND TimeOfSearch BETWEEN 'foo' AND 'bar'

You could always chuck some indexes in there but at 120k rows I don't think that'd make much difference.

With spelling matching there seems to be a few options out the with PHP have you looked into similar_text() or soundex().